# Search view solr Drupal

Tags: solr, drupal-8

i'm having troubles on setting up Search API Solr on Drupal 8.
I have installed the modules:

- Search API
- Search Pages
- Solr search
- Solr search Defaults
- Facets

I have indexed contents and configure the data source to have special content types. When i start a search on the view, solr search api returns two errors:

first is:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in Drupal\search_api_solr\Plugin\search_api\backend\SearchApiSolrBackend->createId() (line 1098 of modules/search_api_solr/src/Plugin/search_api/backend/SearchApiSolrBackend.php).
```

that i found issue was the item id as an array (`{ [0]=> string(16) "entity:node/2:fr" }`) called at extractResults function to get solr_id

following by:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in Drupal\search_api\Query\ResultSet->addResultItem() (line 97 of modules/search_api/src/Query/ResultSet.php).
```

Drupal\search_api\Query\ResultSet->addResultItem(Object) (Line: 1469)

Comment: Did you install the schema for the search api? this sounds like you've just started Solr with the schemaless mode - where all fields are multivalued and returned as arrays to the calling code.

Comment: yes, it's surely a problem of that. Im remember to have a notice that the schema.xml was wrong. How to create a valid schema.xml ?

Comment: Same issue with solr-6.6.5 ,D8.6.7 and search_api_solr module, how you resolve this issue?